# Fineuploader IFrame js file generates syntax error on all browsers

Tags: fine-uploader

This is the error:

```
Message: Object required
Line: 2
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: xyz.com/content/js/fineupload/iframe.xss.response-3.6.4.js
```

This file just have 5 lines:

```
(function() {
    var match = /(\{.+\}).+/.exec(document.body.innerHTML); <- GENERATES ERROR
    if (match) {
        parent.postMessage(match[1], '*');
    }
}());
```

Do we need this file? If yes, why does it generate error?
I am using the latest version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should not be including that file in your client-side source code.  It is meant to be returned as part of a text/html response to a cross-origin upload request from IE8 or IE9.  More info in the [cross-origin support blog post for Fine Uploader](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/31/cors-support-in-3-3/).